# Looping over two sets of files

Tags: bash, loops, for-loop, awk

I have a set of files with the following extension

```
  A.fa
  A_cod.fa
  B.fa
  B_cod.fa
  C.fa
  C_cod.fa
  D.fa
  D_cod.fa
```

For each file I had to do it as

```
 prank -convert -d=A.fa -dna=A_cod.fa -o=A.alignment -keep
```

I wanted to loop over the set of files and do the above instead of each file and tried:

```
  for f in *.fa and for f1 in *_cod.fa; do prank -convert -d=$f -dna=$f1 -o=$f.alignment -keep; done ;
```

But this does not work. So for each file A -d should read in .fa file and -dna should read in the corresponding _cod.fa file and simialrly for B and so on.

Comment: please tag which language you are using to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have a _cod.fa file for each .fa file, we can do this with a single Bash loop:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in *.fa; do
  [[ "${f/*_/}" = "cod.fa" ]] && continue # skip *_cod.fa files
  cod_file="${f//.fa}_cod.fa"
  [[ ! -f "$cod_file" ]] && continue      # _cod.fa doesn't exist
  prank -convert -d="$f" -dna="$cod_file" -o="$f.alignment" -keep
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your files are alphabetically ordered and are not named with white-space characters, you can use `columns` and a while loop like this:

```
ls | columns -c2 | while read cod_fa fa; do 
    prank -convert -d=$fa -dna=$cod_fa -o=A.alignment -keep
done
```

You better test the loop with an echo in-front of `prank` first.

Comment: Thanks Thor but that was just a sample and the files are not alphabetical at all so am not sure if it will work in my situation.

Comment: @Paul: Okay, then you need to be more accurate about the requirements. Perhaps read the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) about examples.

Comment: @Paul: the alphabetic assumption mentioned only requires the the `.fa` and the `_cod.fa` files to be named the same.